# Loopback multiple where clause client side

Tags: javascript, angularjs, strongloop, loopback

I'm trying to use the AngularJS SDK of Loopback but i didn't find a way to do a request with multiple where clause (and there are no examples in the documentation).

```
$scope.events = Professional.events({
        id: '1',
        filter: {
          where: {
            EndDate: {gt: new Date("2017-05-20T00:00:00.000Z")}
          }
        }
      },
    function(err) {
      [...]
    });
```

This example perfectly works but I want to do this:

```
$scope.events = Professional.events({
        id: '1',
        filter: {
          where: {
            and: {
              EndDate: {gt: new Date("2017-05-20T00:00:00.000Z")},
              EndDate: {it: new Date("2017-06-20T00:00:00.000Z")}
            }
          }
        }
      },
    function(err) {
      [...]
    });
```

The error displayed in the terminal

```
Error: The and operator has invalid clauses {"EndDate":{"it":"2017-06-20T00:00:00.000Z"}}: Value is not an array or object with sequential numeric indices
```

Another try:

```
$scope.events = Professional.events({
    id: '1',
    filter: {
      where: {
        EndDate: {gt: new Date("2017-05-20T00:00:00.000Z")},
        EndDate: {it: new Date("2017-06-20T00:00:00.000Z")}
      }
    }
  },
function(err) {
  [...]
});
```

The exact same error code is displayed.
Any idea ?

**EDIT: This solution doesn't work**

```
$scope.events = Professional.events({
        id: '1',
        filter: {
          where: {
            and: [
              {EndDate: {gt: new Date("2017-05-20T00:00:00.000Z")} },
              {EndDate: {it: new Date("2017-06-20T00:00:00.000Z")} }
            ]

          }
        }
      }
      ,
    function(err) {
      [...]
    });
```

The code error (500 http)

```
Erreur non traitée pour la demande GET /api/Professionals/1/events?filter=%7B%22where%22:%7B%22and%22:%5B%7B%22EndDate%22:%7B%22gt%22:%222017-05-20T00:00:00.000Z%22%7D%7D,%7B%22EndDate%22:%7B%22it%22:%222017-06-20T00:00:00.000Z%22%7D%7D%5D%7D%7D : Error: Date non valide : [object Object]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to compare multiple conditions with `and` you have to pass an array to and like this:

```
where: 
{
    and: [
        {title: 'My title'}, 
        {content: 'Hello'}
    ]
}
```

The above code means give me all data where title is 'My title' and content is 'Hello'.

In your case it would be:

```
where: {
    and: [
        { EndDate: {gt: new Date("2017-05-20T00:00:00.000Z")} },
        { EndDate: {it: new Date("2017-06-20T00:00:00.000Z")} }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It doesn't really work (I edited my first post). Or maybe your solution solved the first problem but a new one has been created.

Comment: that error is not about the where clause, you have problem with dates now, happy investigation

Comment: Thanks for your time